# Issues with @mention function

Tags: chatter-groups

Before adding an external user in a group members from the group were able to use @mention function to notify the group in comments. But after an external customer has been added to the group, members can no longer use the function @ mention.

Help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot @mention a group if it has customers..

> You can only mention private groups that you’re a member of, and if
>   the private group contains customers, you can’t mention it even if
>   you’re a member.

here's official salesforce article with the details

[Group mentions in Chatter](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2013/10/group-mentions-in-chatter.html)